# Regex pattern for a string that ends with a space then a letter

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, string

I’m trying to make a regex pattern that would return true for when the string ends with a single letter.

> Hello dear - false
>
> Hello D - true
>
> HelloD - false

Tried `/\[^/sA-Z\]/` but of course that did not work :(

Comment: Try `/\s[a-zA-Z]$/`

Comment: Or `(?:^| )[A-Z]$` if you want to match either a space or `(?:^|\s)[A-Z]$` for a whitespace char if a single character is also valid.

Comment: Are these the only three cases you'll be dealing with?

Comment: `/\[^/sA-Z\]/` is a syntax error in JavaScript, so you might want to start checking for typos

Comment: A regex pattern does not return `true` or `false` on its own. It must be used with some method, and we don't know how you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the end ($) flag

```
/\s[A-Za-z]$/
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Ends in single letter

```
function isAllaz() {
  let a = ["Hello dear", "Hello D", "HelloD"];
  let o = a.map(s => {return `${s} - ${(s.match(/^.* [A-Za-z]$/))? 'true': 'false'}`});
  console.log(JSON.stringify(o));
}

Execution log
10:38:41 PM Notice  Execution started
10:38:42 PM Info    ["Hello dear - false","Hello D - true","HelloD - false"]
10:38:42 PM Notice  Execution completed
```